# Fabric Installation error in ios as 'uploadDSYM: No such file or directory'?

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

By adding the Fabric to the iOS it's giving me error as No such `uploadDSYM` file over there. Have added the Fabric to a `POD` and after adding the `POD` file When I am build the project its showing the error.

> uploadDSYM: No such file or directory

Any help?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps for installation? Please check this for more information : https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

Comment: Please check run script path in target Build Pase.

Comment: Mike from Fabric. I'd double-check the path. For CocoaPod users, the uploadDsym path is set to as the default: "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/uploadDsym"

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved by removing pod lock file and pods folder and install pod again.

**Step 1**
Go to the folder having pods folder and `Podfile.lock`

[image]

**Step 2**

Go to Terminal and copy paste the path of your project having this `podfile` and then install pod files via typing pod install.

Maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

My project folder accidentally had two spaces (next to each other) which caused the same issue.  Deleting the extra space fixed it.  Probably removing all spaces would have also.